# Web Part view for Department Contants

Tags: web-part

I have a contact list with NameAndExtension (Link type), Title (Text field), DepartmentSort. I tried variety of way or different web parts to make the list look like attached screen shot but they are not appearing this way. Any idea how to achieve this view on a web part?

Here is how the list looks like

```
NameAndExtension              Title               DepartmentSort
Brenda Oilers (Ext. 4444)     VP                  1
Steve Austin (Ext. 7777)      Director            2
John Mark (Ext. 7747)         Special Projects    4
Gill Clark (Ext. 8874)        Special Projects    4
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have changed the view by mistake. And in your current view some grouping is selected.
You need to change the View.

- Click on Modify View in Ribbon
- Select the Columns you want to show(Check the check boxes)
- MAKE SURE GROUPING IS NOT SELECTED with any column(currently in looks like in your snapshot that you have selected 'Title' as grouping.

For details on how to customize your view, [Please visit this link](http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-lists-how-to-use-them-to-be-more-efficient/#.U70s9fmSyQw)

Comment: Varun: Right now it's a CEWP but I want to change to LVWP or whatever webpart that will give me the same look.

Comment: you have to use LVWP

Comment: Please mark it answer if it solves your query

Comment: varun: don't you think I have already tried what you have suggested. The LVWP does not give similar look and feel that's why I wanted to an opinion from someone on how to use a list to display the data like I attached above.

Comment: i need to confirm from you & i don't think it's a bad idea to confirm first. Did you tried to edit the LVWP and change the view?

Comment: Yes, I can edit the lvwp in SPdesigner and get to final look.